# Save each PDF file of a directory as another PDF (operation similar to print a PDF as a PDF)

Tags: printing, pdf

Consider the following procedure:

1) Open a PDF file using the (Ubuntu) document viewer.

2) Goto File

3) Goto Print

4) Choose 'Print as file' and check the mark "pdf"

Yes, I am printing a PDF as PDF file. I have to do this for a large collection of files. I would like to do this running a script at the terminal.

Maybe you think that this procedure does not make any sense at all, but it actually was the only safe way I found to deal with the issue considered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384591/parsing-a-pdf-with-no-root-object-using-pdfminer). This StackOverflow question shows a problem with PDF files the EOF marker is not found. When I do the procedure described above, I am able to solve this problem [This is not the solution presented in StackOverflow site, which does not work here.]

I would like to this automatically with all files that present this issue.

I know that I should build one script (.sh) to this, but I do not know how to proceed.

An example of the PDF file (1) with problems is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bJYoCST5jSNed2i-EGtnb33v9i2ktYH9)

The corrected PDF file (2) is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OBVL7FRqQmIKNJ0hDeQTwoguvAVe7-YN)

The only difference between them is that I opened the first using the "Ubuntu Document Viewer", I went to "File", "Print", "Print to File", "Output=pdf".

I want to make this automatically.

**EDIT:**

**I do NOT want to merge the files.**

Comment: Do you want to print them (on paper, using a printer) or "save them in another directory from terminal"?

Comment: Save in another directory as pdf.

Comment: However, I do not want to copy them.

Comment: So you want to copy them? Are you just looking for a script that will run `cp orig.pdf copy.pdf` for each file? You've linked to an SO question with a lot of text and a lot of python, why is that relevant? Please [edit] and explain what you need.

Comment: No, I do not want to copy them. It is like to open a file, open the printer and save as a pdf. It is a different procedure. This procedure changes the pdf. The copy procedure only changes the place where the pdf is kept.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain then. A printer is a physical device, so I assume you don't really mean "open the printer".

Comment: Do you perhaps wish to fix or re-render corrupted PDFs?

Comment: "The pdfminer error mentioned above": what is this error? How can we reproduce it so we can test our answers? If it is explained in the linked [so] question, then please reproduce the relevant information here.

Comment: Thanks @terdon. I included this information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `cups-pdf` installed and added as printer. Note pdf printer name. (Optional) Edit `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`: uncomment and change the line where is says `#Out /var/spool/cups-pdf/${USER}` to the desired output directory.

Then restart CUPS: `sudo systemctl restart cups`

Now in order to print do:

```
SOURCEDIR="/path/to/source/pdfs"
for i in "$SOURCEDIR"
do
    lpr -P <pdf printer name> "$i"
done
```

Now copy the files from the default output directory to the desired location, if you didn't edit `cups-pdf.conf`

<del>Install `poppler-utils` and run `pdfunite input1.pdf input2.pdf input3.pdf output.pdf`.</del>

Comment: There are about hundred pdfs

Comment: And you want to make them all 100 into one pdf?

Comment: No I want to print each pdf file as a file one by one.

Comment: This way to handle the problem is very in-effective and may lead to new problems with the modified files. A better method would be to use Ghostscript directly....

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want most easily with the help of Ghostscript. I successfully tested this with Ghostscript version 9.26:

```
gs                  \
  -o out.pdf        \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   in.pdf
```

I must admit, I do not really comprehend your problem with the EOF marker in the [***unmodified*** example file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bJYoCST5jSNed2i-EGtnb33v9i2ktYH9), because I can clearly see this EOF marker being present in it.

However, I see an additional problem which shows in your [***'corrected'*** example file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OBVL7FRqQmIKNJ0hDeQTwoguvAVe7-YN): this one now uses a page size of A4 (595 x 842 pts) with large white margins, whereas your unmodified file has small margins and a page size of 362 x 558 pts (which is less than half of A4!)

My method has the advantage to preserve the original page sizes.

To apply it to all PDF files in the current directory, including all sub-directories, use the following command:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f | while read line; do
    gs -o mod-${line} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "${line}"
done
```